# How adding event handler inside a class with a class-method as the callback?

Tags: javascript, oop, event-handling

How do I add an event handler inside a class with a class-method as the callback?

```
<div id="test">move over here</div>
<script>
    oClass = new CClass();
    function CClass()
    {
        this.m_s = "hello :-/";
        this.OnEvent = OnEvent;
        with(this)
        {
            var r = document.getElementById("test");
            r.addEventListener('mouseover', this.OnEvent);  // this does NOT work :-/
        }
      
        function OnEvent()
        {
            alert(this);    // this will be the HTML div-element
            alert(this.m_s);    // will be undefined :-()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Yes I know some quirks to make it work but what would be the intended way when these event handlers were introduced ??? I again have the bitter feeling, that no-one truly lives OOP :-(

Here for you to play: https://jsfiddle.net/sepfsvyo/1/

Comment: Note that the `with` statement is strongly discouraged, and is disallowed in Strict mode. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `this` inside the event listener callback will be the element that fired the event. If you want the `this` to be the instance of your class, then either:

**Bind the function to the class instance:**

Using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), will create a new function that its `this` value will always be what you specify it to be (the class instance):

```
r.addEventListener('mouseover', this.OnEvent.bind(this));
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Wrap the function inside an anonymous function:**

```
var that = this;
r.addEventListener('mouseover', function(ev) { that.OnEvent(ev); });
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (so no need for `that`):

```
r.addEventListener('mouseover', ev => this.OnEvent(ev));
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Note:** As mentioned in a comment bellow, both of the above methods pass a different function to `addEventListener` (the one with `bind` create a new function, and the anounimous function is obviously `!== this.OnEvent`). If you are going to remove the event listener later, you'll have to store a reference to the function:

```
var reference;
r.addEventListener('mouseover', reference = this.OnEvent.bind(this));
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or:

```
var reference;
var that = this;
r.addEventListener('mouseover', reference = function(ev) { that.OnEvent(ev); });
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then you can remove the event listener like:

```
r.removeEventListener('mouseover', reference);
```

Comment: thank you for the bind-function. I guess proper oop style would be to bind in the method declaration `this.OnEvent = OnEvent.bind(this);` :-) Binding at the end of the definition will freeze (only) Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 :-( see here: https://jsfiddle.net/sepfsvyo/3/

Comment: if you added a couple of these event handlers, how would you go about removing one of them? it seems with anon functions you loose ability to turn off this.OnEvent  later.?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing I was goint to add a note about it when I posted the answer, but felt there is no need for that. Now that I have a second opinion about it, I added the note.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ah, that's what I was missing.  so in a class, `window.addEventListener('message', this.msgref= function(e){that.handleMessage(e)})` will it work?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing yes, If `this` is the instance of the class (if that line of code is in a method or constructor, not in a another functions that has its `this` bound to something else).

Comment: @AwokeKnowing So for example, in his code he's doing this: `this.OnEvent = OnEvent;`. Instead he coud just do this: `r.addEventListener('mouseover', this.OnEvent = OnEvent.bind(this));`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks. I guess to my shame I've mostly just added events without cleaning up... I wasn't sure how to get a reference while still controlling `this`

Comment: @AwokeKnowing Attaching event to method is tricky, everything wants to take controll of `this`.

Answer (score 15):

You can actually return the object as an EventListener callback, this way JS will search for an `handleEvent` method in the class and execute accordingly :

```js
var myInstance = new myClass;
myInstance.addEventListener("mousedown",myInstance);

//  To remove the event you can follow the same pattern
myInstance.removeEventListener("mousedown",myInstance);
```

You have to construct your class this way :

```js
class myClass {
   
    constructor(){
        //  Whatever this is supposed to do.
        //  You can also add events listener within the class this way :
        this.addEventListener("mousedown",this);
    }
    
    mouseDownEvent(e)(){
        //  Some action related to the mouse down event (e)
        console.log(e.target);
    }
    mouseMoveEvent(e)(){
        //  Some action related to the mouse move event (e)
    }
    mouseUpEvent(e)(){
        // Some action related to the mouse up event (e)
    }

    handleEvent(e) {
        switch(e.type) {
            case "mousedown":
                this.mouseDownEvent(e);
            break;
            case "mousemove":
                this.mouseMoveEvent(e);
            break;
            case "mouseup":
                this.mouseUpEvent(e);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Sources :

https://medium.com/@WebReflection/dom-handleevent-a-cross-platform-standard-since-year-2000-5bf17287fd38

https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/handleevent

https://metafizzy.co/blog/this-in-event-listeners/

I find this method clearer, also while declaring events inside the class `this` is pretty explicit.
Hope I helped someone.

Comment: thks to pointing me to this . I never heard about handleEvent before and this is really awesome. It works perfectly !

Comment: I find this cleaner as well.

Comment: For more information on `handleEvent`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#syntax and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback

Answer (score 2):

The answer from **@ibrahimmahrir** does the job, but I wanted to consolidate a few points.

As many JavaScript developers struggle to understand, the `this` keyword is a moving target. In traditional OOP languages, an object method is exclusive to the object, so `this` is defined as the object to which it is attached.

JavaScript functions are more promiscuous, and can be attached to multiple objects. In JavaScript, `this` refers to the object which is *currently* invoking the function, not necessarily the one to which it was originally attached.

For an Event Handler function, the invoking object is the *element* to which it is attached, not the original object; thus `this` refers to the element. The *usual* safe method is to store a reference to the original object in a different variable, often called `that`:

```js
oClass = new CClass();
function CClass() {
    var that = this;        //  a reference to the original object
    this.m_s = "hello :-/";
    this.OnEvent = OnEvent;
    var r = document.getElementById("test");
    r.addEventListener('click', this.OnEvent);

    function OnEvent() {
        alert(that);        //  this is now the object
        alert(that.m_s);    //  this works
    }
}
```

The comments above are my updated comments. I have also removed the `with` statement which wasn’t contributing much and which is seriously discouraged.

Oh, and I have changed the event to `click` to make it easier to test.

While we’re on the confusion with `this`, it is not necessarily the element which started things off. Suppose we now include a `span`:

```html
<div id="test">click <span>over</span> here</div>
```

Clicking on the `span` will trigger the event listener, even though the you didn’t actually click on the `div` to which it is attached. In this case the event is bubbled from the span to the div.

Here `this` refers only to the `div` element with the event listener. If you want to reference the `span`, you will need `event.target`:

```js
function OnEvent(event) {   //  include event parameter
    alert(this);            //  the element attached
    alert(event.target);    //  the element clicked
    alert(that);            //  this is now the object
    alert(that.m_s);        //  this works
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/osk083xv/