# Passing additional info into EventListener callback

Tags: javascript

I try to call the same method from an object instance itself as well as from a EventListener. In this method I need to access some object attributes/methods via `this`. This does not work with the EventListener since in case the `this` var does not refer to the object instance but to the element that triggered the EventListener. Minimal example here:

```js
function App() {
  this.selectBox = document.querySelector("#foo");
}

App.prototype.run = function() {
  this.selectBox.addEventListener('change', this.selected, false);
  this.selected();
}

App.prototype.selected = function() {
  // In this method 'this' referes to the App instance in case of the
  // call on line 7.
  // if the method in called via EventListener (line 6), this referes 
  // to the element that triggered the EventListener. In this case I am
  // not able to access any properties or methods of the object instance.

  var t = document.querySelector("#this");
  t.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(this);

  var o = document.querySelector("#out");
  o.innerHTML = this.selectBox.value;
}

a = new App();
a.run();
```

```html
<select id="foo">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<div>SELECTED: <span id="out"></span></div>
<div>'this' in method/callback is: <span id="this"></span></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7eayc9ks/5/

Is there any (idiomatic) way to pass the required instance information (eg. a reference to the object instance) into the EventListener callback?

Comment: Well you could hard bind it, or if you wan to be more flexible use a little bit of closures and currying to inject additional parameters. That's what you want? :)

Comment: TLDR: `() => obj.method()` instead of `obj.method`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43727516/9867451 might help