# Javascript Class References in Html

Tags: javascript, html, class

Assuming I have a class `class FooBar() {}` with a method `doSomething(){}`, can I create and append a html element from within the class itself that calls `doSomething()` when clicked?. Here is a code snippet:

```
class FooBar{
    constructor(options){this.options = options}
    doSomething(){ /* onclick functionality */}
    creator(){
        let reference = `<div onclick="this.doSomething()"></div>`;
        document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].innerHtml = reference;

    }
}
```

I would now like to know the correct way of writing the `let reference . . .` line.

Comment: Yes, you can create an element and append it to the document, but that's not how you create elements, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: Also a typo is there: `getElementByTagName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to attach the event listener you can't use `innerHTML` because `onclick="this.doSomething()"` in your string won't point to your class. You have to construct the element using `document.createElement` and append that using `appendChild`.

Second, when you attach the event listener, make sure the proper `this` is used (more on that in this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43727516/9867451)). We'll just use a simple arrow function. We'll also use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` which is more standard:

```
class FooBar{
    constructor(options) { this.options = options; }
    doSomething() { /* onclick functionality */}
    creator() {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.addEventListener("click", ev => this.doSomething( /* pass 'ev' here if you want */ ));

        // it's ok to use div.innerHTML here to fill out the div instead of createElement/appendChild

        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `addEventListener` instead of using `onclick` on the tag

```js
let newElement = document.createElement('div')
newElement.addEventListenser('click', () => console.log('clicked'))
```