# Why does Javascript require event listeners to be functions that return functions?

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

I'm trying to generate a grid that responds to clicks and mouseover events. I have a tile manager object that holds tile objects, each of which have their own event listener. Currently, the actual method that gets called is in the manager object, though I would prefer they exist in the tile objects.

I would like to either find a solution more elegant than the one I currently know works, or at least understand why this solution even works at all when others do not:

*for reference and clarity, `cell` refers to the javacript object and `cell_node` refers to a DOM object in the cell, additionally `_handleClick` and `click_callback` are the same function*

Currently, to see if a callback happened, I have defined my callback as:

```
    _handleClick(el,r,c,i){
        console.log("element:" + el)
        console.log("row:" + r)
        console.log("col:" + c)
        console.log("index:" + i)
    }
```

Where `_handleClick(el,r,c,i)` is located in the manager object, not the tiles.

The `addEventListener` method looks like this:

```
cell_node.addEventListener('click',
                (function(el,r,c,i){
                    return function(){
                        click_callback(el,r,c,i);
                    }
                })(cell,r,c,i),false);
```

I cannot even begin to understand why this is necessary, or why it works when attempts such as:

```
cell_node.addEventListener('click', cell.some_clicked_function_with_no_arguments)
```

do not work. If I define `cell.some_clicked_function_with_no_arguments` with the `this` keyword, everything prints out as undefined, leaving me even more confused.

The two methods are posted in full below

```
class gridTile{
    constructor(row, col, tile_id){
        this.text= row + ", " + col;
        this.child_text_div = this._make_child_text_div(this.text);
        this.element = this._make_root_element()
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.id = tile_id;
    }
    _get_root_style(){
        var randomColor = '#'+(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
        return `
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 100%;
            //height: ${this.height}%;
            background-color: ${randomColor};
            position: relative;
            `;
    }
    _make_child_text_div(text){
        var cssobject =`
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        `;
        var obj = document.createElement("div");
        obj.setAttribute("style", cssobject);
        obj.innerHTML = text;
        return obj;
    }
    _make_root_element(){
        var root_grid_div = document.createElement("div");
        root_grid_div.setAttribute("style", this._get_root_style());
        root_grid_div.appendChild(this.child_text_div);
        return root_grid_div;
    }
    get_element(){return this.element;}

    clicked_callback(cell){
        return function(cell){
            console.log("element:" + cell.element);
            console.log("row:" + cell.row);
            console.log("col:" + cell.col);
            console.log("index:" + cell.tile_id);
        }

    };

}

class Grid{
    constructor(rows, columns){
        this.grid_div = this._generate_grid_div(rows, columns, this._handleClick);
    }

    _generate_grid_div(rows, cols, click_callback){
        // generate styling row and columns
        var row_percent = String(1/rows * 100) + "% ";
        var col_percent = String(1/cols * 100) + "% ";
        console.log(row_percent + ", " + col_percent);

        var rowstyle = "grid-template-rows: ";
        for (var i=0; i<rows; i++){
            rowstyle += row_percent
        }
        var colstyle = "grid-template-columns: ";
        for (var i=0; i<cols; i++){
            colstyle += col_percent
        }
        var style = `
        display: grid;
        ${rowstyle};
        ${colstyle};
        `
        var grid = document.createElement('div');
        grid.className = 'grid';
        grid.setAttribute("style", style)

        var i=0;
        for (var r=0;r<rows;++r){
            for (var c=0;c<cols;++c){

                var cell = new gridTile(r, c, i);
                var cell_node = grid.appendChild(cell.get_element())

                cell_node.addEventListener('click',
                (function(el,r,c,i){
                    return function(){
                        click_callback(el,r,c,i);
                    }
                })(cell,r,c,i),false);

                cell_node.addEventListener('mouseenter', click_callback(cell,r,c,i));

                ++i;
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }

    _handleClick(el,r,c,i){
        console.log("element:" + el)
        console.log("row:" + r)
        console.log("col:" + c)
        console.log("index:" + i)
    }

    get_grid_element(){
        return this.grid_div;
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example, but you need to post more code. Also make sure to understand how that IIFE works (and that you don't necessarily have to place it inside the `addEventListener` arguments list).

Comment: It is indeed a dupe of ^. Best solution would be to use `const` and `let` instead of `var`, and then you just need to do `.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => click_callback(cell,r,c,i))`

Comment: I've added the full code, sorry about that! Additionally, in the link in @Bergi's comment, I notice that the example a bit below uses an anonymous function which I presume works. Why would an anonymous or arrow function work when just pointing to another objects function not? Is this really a scope issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up getting solved by adding an arrow function within a separate method:

```
    _make_root_element(){
        var root_grid_div = document.createElement("div");
        root_grid_div.setAttribute("style", this._get_root_style());
        root_grid_div.appendChild(this.child_text_div);
        this._add_listeners_to_root_element(root_grid_div);
        return root_grid_div;
    }

    get_element(){return this.element;}

    _add_listeners_to_root_element(el){
        el.addEventListener('click', () => this._clicked_callback());
    }

    _clicked_callback(){
        console.log("element:" + this.element);
        console.log("row:" + this.row);
        console.log("col:" + this.col);
        console.log("index:" + this.id);
    };
```

This time, the `this` is not the element that called the event, but is now within the scope of the object the arrow function was defined in. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43727582/9023907) helped me quite a bit in understanding what was going on, when other posts did not do so. This is more a reflection of my lack of ability to understand rather than the efforts of others to explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the `addEventListener()` call in the IIFE instead might make it easier to read for you. As mentioned in comment above there isn't enough shown to know if this can be refactored to remove the IIFE

The following will act exactly the same:

```
(function(el, r, c, i) {
  cell_node.addEventListener('click', function() {
    click_callback(el, r, c, i);
  }, false);
})(cell, r, c, i)
```