# What's the most compact way to add "events" to a JavaScript class in a Node.js module? (in ES6 and above env.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, events, ecmascript-6

Have been looking for the *universal* way to handle events in a class. To be exact, I'm making a node.js module and I want to be able to add multiple callbacks to certain events. Say, my source looks something like this:

```js
class Example {
    constructor(...args) {
        // ...
    }
    doSomething(earg) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // I want an event call here.
            // this.callEvent(eargs) or something like that, to pass 
            // down arguments to callbacks.
        }, 3000);
    }
    on(event, callback, watch) {
        // ...
    }

    once(event, callback, watch) {
        // ...
    }
}

const example = new Example();
example.on('doSomethingEnd', (earg) => console.log(':P', earg));
```

What's the most compact and **modern** way of achieving `.on`s and `.once`s in an ES6 and above environment and how to do "code editor autofill" for such? (For editors like Atom or VSCode, or any other that have syntax hinting).

Comment: Just to clarify things up, do you have any issues with the code or just trying to get a review? I'm personally not sure what does "*most compact and universal way* terms stand for, maybe more experienced users would know that topic. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727516/how-adding-event-handler-inside-a-class-with-a-class-method-as-the-callback?rq=1)?

Comment: @Aleksandar Asking for an exact solution. Also just to clarify, I'm in a `node.js` environment with no document or html elements, I'm making a *node module*. I'll modify the question a little just so it's a little more clear.

Comment: @bouncytorch then why not just use https://nodejs.org/api/events.html?

Comment: @Bergi well I didn't know about it, thank you! That's why I asked this question, plus as far as I can tell there wasn't a similar question on Stack. If there was, someone could flag it as duplicate, cuz I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, Node has a built in class for that (props to @Bergi):

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');

class Example extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(...args) {
        // ...
    }
    doSomething(earg) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.emit('<example>', 'arg0')
        }, 3000);
    }
}

const example = new Example();
example.on('<example>', (earg) => { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: The previous answer was removed because it was ChatGPT-generated, [which isn't allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).